# How to close all child activities from parent in android

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm new to android. Actually one handler is running in Home Activity A for every 30 sec to check the net connection.

If I'm  went to activity C by A->B->C, If there in no net connection at that time, then i want to close Activity B and C, then want to show message box in Activity A.

But My problem is My handler is running for every 30 sec in Home Activity A.      But If i was in Activity C or some other Activity how to find which activity is my Application currently focussed now. Then i want to finish those child activities and want to show Home Activity A I have some 9 child activities in Activity B.

I heard about using "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" . I used the code as follows in the handler in Home activity A itself. But got error.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent( ctx, Homepage.class );    
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    ctx.startActivity( intent );
```

Here Homepage.class is my Home Activity A and i set that activity in manifest file as

```
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Please help!

Comment: Why did you post the same question 3 times within 3 hours? If you have problems with the answers given to your questions, just add a question in a comment

Answer (score 4):

You can start Activity A and close all other activities. 
You have to create new intent and add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
Intent activityA = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
activityA.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.StartActivity(activityA);
```

this will close all activities that are in the stack and are at the top of activity A

Comment: he is asking to kill Child activities

Answer (score 0):

When calling Acitivity C, call finish in activity B , when calling Activity A from C , call finish() in activity C !

Comment: Sorry According to my task, i cant do that, if i press back button it should come to B and should come to A. If i'm in activity C and at that time if net connection got disable, then i want to display message with activity A in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, According to me two ways,

If you start an activity using startActivityForResult, then you can call finish() in this new Activity when you're done with it and it will return control to the activity that started it.

OR otherwise, May be I am wrong,

Call finish inside **onStop** 'override method'.

Comment: No, actually on handler is running in Activity A for every 30 sec to check the net connection. If I'm in activity C, If there  in no net connection, then i want to close Activity B and C, then want to show message box in Activity A. But My problem is My handler cant able to find which activity is focussed now.

Answer (score 0):

make a uniform **resultCode** for closing child activities. Eg. you make **911** (should be int) as your resultCode. If you want your Activity to finish and go back directly to parent Activity, you set the resultCode to 911:

`setResult(911); finish();`

In every child activity, you override the onActivityResult and check if the resultCode is 911. If yes, then call the `setResult(911); finish();` until you get back to your parent activity. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to start intentB, you can do following in old activity:


`Intent intentB = new Intent();

intentB.setClass(XYZ.this, abc.class);

intentB.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intentB);`