# How to close all child activities from parent in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close all child activities from parent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302640/how-to-close-all-child-activities-from-parent-in-android)

I'm new to android. Actually one handler is running in Home Activity A for every 30 sec to check the net connection. If I'm in activity C, If there in no net connection at that time, then i want to close Activity B and C, then want to show message box in Activity A. But My problem is My handler cant able to find which activity is focussed now. I have some 9 child activities in Activity B. I heard about using "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" . But i don't know how to use it in handler. Please help me.